# "More StackExchange communities" list, "Русский язык"

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, languages

If you click the Stack Exchange site drop-down menu:

> [image: bigger image]

and look closely at the  menu item for "Русский язык", you'll see the following:

> [image: menu item for Russian language].

At the moment it is read as

> "For лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка"

Just two notes:

- It is better to put "Для" instead of "For".
- According to rules, the comma before "и" is an error.

So, the whole line should be written as:

> "Для лингвистов, этимологов и энтузиастов русского языка"

Comment: related: [Oxford comma](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199098/165773)

Comment: Also, why is it way down at the bottom, shouldn't it be with the other "P"/"R" sites?

Comment: Not in Russian.  A series of words like this => there is no comma before the "and."  No exceptions.
(Colorful picture!)

Comment: I'm... not sure we can easily fix that. Well, without deploying a highly sophisticated upgrade to the localization enging. (`if Locale == Russian then prefix = "Для"` :))

Comment: @AnnaLear I don't know the code, but maybe it would be easier to remove the 'for' part as a standard and add it to the description? Because it applies to may other languages also. For example, the Japanese discription as visible in the list.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Are you talking about OS' or browser's locale? Mine are en_US.

Comment: @wythagoras: You are right, it is the easiest way to correct it.

Comment: @wythagoras Localization is a complex beast. For example, the Russian site's audience is phrased with the expectation of a word like "for" in front of it. Russian carries a lot of information in word endings (unlike, say, English).

Comment: @DIGmbl No. You should assume that my comment bears just about no resemblance to what actual code would look like. :)